# How do I set the default oninvalid text on f.number_field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

When a user enters a non-integer into my `f.number_field`, the user gets a validation error that says, `"Please enter a number."` Users are entering commas into the input. Is there a way to add the `oninvalid` attribute to `f.number_field`?

Comment: Is the validation error happening after they submit? Which means you need to do server-side validation, right? Not client-side.

Comment: Yes it is happening when they try to hit submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arbitrary options to the tag, so just pass your `:oninvalid` attribute with your value.

```
<%= form.number_field(:age, :oninvalid = "something happened bro!") %>
```

Comment: Nope. It's still displaying the HTML5 oninvalid default.

Comment: And you are viewing the HTML source and you can see that your `:oninvalid` is being used?

Answer (score 0):

I'm only learning ruby and have never coded in it before, but how about this?

```
puts "Please enter a number." unless form.number_field.isa? Integer
```